# Heroku scheduled function using Heroku Scheduler Python

Tags: python, heroku, async-await, discord.py

So I'm developing a discord bot using the python.py API and I'm trying to make it write a certain thing every day using Heroku Scheduler, but I cannot make it work. The main problem is that every function to interact with discord needs to be asynchronous, but the call cannot be made outside an async function, like such:

```py
async def hi():
   channel = bot.get_channel(int(general)) #get the general channel from the id
   await channel.send("Hello")

await hi() #not allowed (outside async func)
hi() #needs to be awaited
```

Since Heroku Scheduler needs to be fed a job that runs a whole script (e.g. python scheduler.py), I don't see a way to make the function work. So, if I remove the await keyboard it obviously does not work. If I remove the async/await keywords, it cannot interact with discord because it is not asynchronous, and if I leave it as it is in the example, it says I cannot have hi() called outside an async function. How am I supposed to do this?
Thanks in advance.